# Does Cloud Functions allow outbound port scan?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I need my Cloud Function to check whether a particular ip:port is open, sort of like an `nmap`. It's basically monitoring whether a server in my office is online and has an internet connection. I see there's a `node-portscanner` library. Will that work in Cloud Functions?

Comment: I think the easiest thing for you to do here is to just try it.  Your project will need to be on a billing plan.  If all it's doing is making output TCP connections to a publicly accessible IP and port, it should be OK.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll give it a try, and report back the result.

Comment: Most smart firewalls will detect a port scan. If you are just checking one port number, no problem. If you are connecting to more than a couple of port numbers, you might get locked out. I am not aware of a Google specific policy regarding port scanning, but most cloud providers do not allow this unless you own the resources you are scanning. I reviewed both the Acceptable Use Policy and Terms of Service and this was not mentioned. https://cloud.google.com/terms/aup and https://cloud.google.com/terms/

Comment: I've confirmed that I'm able to use portscanner to verify whether an ip:port is open. I'll post the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed that a Google Cloud Function running in the datacenter can use the `portscanner` library to verify whether an ip:port is open.

Incidentally, the `dns` library is also able to lookup ip addresses for hostnames.